# TFS user profile

Tags: tfs

We have Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server. Version 15.117.26714.0.
Our sql server have many databases.

5 of them have the prefix tfs_ This is tfs_warehouse, tfs_configuration, (collections… tfs_M1, tfs_M2, tfs_M3)

Tell me, please, where user profile information is stored (for example, email).

[image]

There is no information in the tables TFS_WAREHOUSE.DimPerson and TFS_CONFIGURATION.tbl_Identity tables.

Comment: What the results on `TFS_WAREHOUSE.DimPerson`? because I can see the name & email there.

Comment: We have email and name fields with data in TFS_WAREHOUSE.DimPerson. But this info we get from windows active directory. After change email in tfs user profile, we do not have change in field TFS_WAREHOUSE.DimPerson.email

Answer (score 1):

For us, the **answer is**

database: tfs_configuration

SELECT Name, PropertyId FROM tbl_PropertyDefinition WHERE Name in ('ConfirmedNotificationAddress','CustomNotificationAddresses')
/*26,27*/

SELECT Description, InternalKindId FROM tbl_PropertyArtifactKind
WHERE Description='Identity'
/*1*/

select * from tbl_PropertyValue pv where pv.InternalKindId=1 and PropertyId in (26,27)